# How to update the state declared in parent component to a child component using react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-modal

My react project contains two components: one is parent and another is child. My parent component looks like this:

```
import React, {useState } from 'react';
import AddNewModal from './AddNewModal';

const MouseContainer = (props) =>{
const [show,setShow] = useState(false);
const toggle = () => setShow(!show);
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Toggle</button>
        <p>{show && <AddNewModal show={props.show} setShow={props.setShow}/>}</p>
    </div>
     )
}export default MouseContainer;
```

And a child component that renders the modal like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AddNewForm from './AddNewForm';

const AddNewModal = (show,setShow) => {
return(
    <div>
    <Modal show={show} setShow={setShow}> 
    <Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body><AddNewForm/></Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={(props)=>props.setShow(!show)}>
        Cancel
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}export default AddNewModal;
```

How can I update the stat so that the "cancel" button close the modal when clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're controlling the modal with the `useState` hook. If that is so, your problem is regarding which props you are passing to the `AddNewModal` component.

You're creating the hook correctly with:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

However, you're passing the wrong props to the `AddNewModal` component. You're passing a `setShow` and a `show` coming from props in the `MouseContainer` component, here:

```
<p>{show && <AddNewModal show={props.show} setShow={props.setShow} />}</p>
```

However, to use the hook you should pass the variables you declared:

```
<p>{show && <AddNewModal show={show} setShow={setShow} />}</p>
```

I'm not familiar with the bootstrap framework, but I think the prop `show` of the modal component is controlling whether the modal is being shown or not. If that's the case, you can remove the conditional render as well, resulting in:

```
<AddNewModal show={show} setShow={setShow} />
```

Here's your updated code for the `MouseContainer` component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AddNewModal from './AddNewModal';

const MouseContainer = (props) => {
  const [show,setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setShow(!show);

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Toggle</button>
        <AddNewModal show={show} setShow={setShow} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also, you have a small type on the `AddNewModal`:

To immediately get the props fields you want on the Functional Component declaration, one must use object destructuring [1], to do that one use curly braces:

`const AddNewModal = ({ show, setShow }) => {`

Doing so, you're not declaring the `props` object like you're doing in the `MouseContainer` component. So you can't use it within the function.

Here's you updated `AddNewModal`:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AddNewForm from './AddNewForm';

const AddNewModal = ({ show, setShow }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={show} setShow={setShow}> 
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body><AddNewForm/></Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Sources:

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there just to make this below change

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AddNewForm from './AddNewForm';

const AddNewModal = ({show,setShow}) => {
return(
    <div>
    <Modal show={show}> 
    <Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body><AddNewForm/></Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>
        Cancel
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```